# Angular 2 hide component selectors

Tags: angular

When examining Angular 2 Apps like Google Maps or YouTube i never see any component selectors like  or  in html source.

Is this default for production build? Or is it always needed for Angular 2 to work?

I got three problems with this:

1. They dont look good (minor)
2. They reveal my app is Angular 2 (minor)
3. They break the CSS layout e.g. when using flexbox (major)

Answer (score 1):

It's always needed. Google Maps and YouTube are not made with angular. Check https://material.angular.io/. This site from google/angular is made with angular. If you inspect the elements you see all the selectors: `<app-homepage>`, `<router-outlet>`.. etc. That's just how it works. They are not going to port such big code bases as Google Maps or YouTube to a new framework :)

1. It actually gives a nice semantic structure if you ask me, instead of a random `div` you get a component selector. So you know exactly what that component is doing.
2. Yes, you are using the latest technology out there, can't really be a negative :)
3. In what way are they breaking your layout? If they are, it kinda means you are not using it right, or you are expecting a different result than given. Perhaps post a code example or a fiddle where it 'breaks' for you?

Comment: There are some questions out there for #3. And I don't like the workarounds tbh.

Comment: I use flex throughout my entire application, and never had issues with it. Or at least, the html acted like i expect it to act. Perhaps you can use [**this**](https://github.com/angular/flex-layout)?

Comment: If a container has display:flex and the child ist <app-component> instead of the real child the flex-layout is broken.